# Descision trees and splits on categorical variables with many levels?

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, multilevel-analysis, many-categories

[This exercise document](https://www.soa.org/4a18f6/globalassets/assets/files/edu/2022/spring/solutions/2022-04-14-exam-pa-model-sol.pdf#page=25) ask the following question (page 25):

> Your assistant, A, builds a decision tree to investigate which
> variables have a significant impact on response time. The variable
> **day**, when used as a categorical variable, is deemed important by the
> tree-based model. A knows from experience, and from testing other
> models, that **day** is not actually a significant variable.
>
> Explain why a decision tree model may emphasize **day** which is a less
> important categorical variable with 31 levels, when used as a
> categorical variable, despite it not being an important variable.

They give the following answer, but not sure about the reason why this holds:

> Decision trees tend to create splits on categorical variables with
> many levels because it is easier to choose a split where the
> information gain is large. However, splitting on these variables will
> likely to lead to overfitting.

Can you please help me explain this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which flavor of decision tree: CART, which always does binary splits (and from the context I assume can split a categorical into an arbitrary bipartition); or the Quinlan tree, which splits all the values in a categorical into children at once?

Comment: ...I suppose the second quote suggests the former?

Comment: @BenReiniger After googling around, the quotations seem to come from the following document (this is some textbook or series of exam questions, with the answers provided along), page 25 https://www.soa.org/4a18f6/globalassets/assets/files/edu/2022/spring/solutions/2022-04-14-exam-pa-model-sol.pdf#page=25 .